Finding beta functions of $\phi^4$ from bare and physical mass
Suppose I have a massive $\lambda\phi^4$ theory in $D=4$. In $\overline{MS}$ we have to add a counterterm
$$\delta m^2=-\frac{\lambda m^2}{32\pi^2}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}+\ln(4\pi)-\gamma_E\right),$$
due to the tadpole diagram (see e.g. http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/dbs26/AQFT.html chapter 5). Then the bare mass is
$$m_0^2=m^2\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{32\pi^2}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}+\ln(4\pi)-\gamma_E\right)\right).$$
The latter is $\mu$ independent and therefore
$$0=\beta_{m^2}\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{32\pi^2}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}+\ln(4\pi)-\gamma_E\right)\right)-\frac{m^2\beta_\lambda}{32\pi^2}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}+\ln(4\pi)-\gamma_E\right).$$
For small $\epsilon$ only the $1/\epsilon$ are relevant and therefore
$$\lambda\beta_{m^2}=-m^2\beta_\lambda.$$
Now, we can solve for the beta functions by introducing another quantity independent of $\mu$. For this consider the physical mass, as the pole of the two-point function (see again the lecture notes above)
$$m_p^2=m^2-\Sigma(m_p^2)=m^2\left(1+\frac{\lambda\hbar}{32\pi^2}\ln\left(\frac{\mu^2}{m^2}\right)\right).$$
In this case the independence guarantees that
$$0=\beta_{m^2}\left(1+\frac{\lambda\hbar}{32\pi^2}\ln\left(\frac{\mu^2}{m^2}\right)\right)+m^2\left(\frac{\beta_\lambda\hbar}{32\pi^2}\ln\left(\frac{\mu^2}{m^2}\right)+\frac{\lambda\hbar}{16\pi^2}-\frac{\lambda\hbar}{32\pi^2m^2}\beta_{m^2}\right)=\beta_{m^2}+(\lambda\beta_{m^2}+m^2\beta_\lambda)\frac{\hbar}{32\pi^2}\ln\left(\frac{\mu}{m^2}\right)+\frac{\lambda m^2\hbar}{16\pi^2}-\frac{\lambda\hbar}{32\pi^2}\beta_{m^2}.$$
Combining this with the previous results shows that
$$\beta_{m^2}=2m^2\frac{1}{1-\frac{32\pi^2}{\lambda \hbar}}=-\frac{\lambda m^2\hbar}{16\pi^2},$$
up to order $\lambda$. Then we have
$$\beta_\lambda=\frac{\lambda^2\hbar}{16\pi^2}.$$
This is however wrong according to the notes :( It should instead be
$$\beta_\lambda=\frac{3\lambda^2\hbar}{32\pi^2},$$
which is $3/2$ of the value we found. Can someone help me figure our where is the factor of $3/2$ I am missing? I think if this can be corrected it would be really cool because it would give $\beta_\lambda$ without computing any diagrams with four external legs.

The expression for the pole mass I gave above is wrong. Below is the correct expression and a proof that it is inconsistent to have both the bare and pole masses to be independent of $\mu$.
Let us remark that at one loop, the amputated tadpole diagram contributing to the self-energy in Euclidean spacetime is
$$\Sigma(p^2)=-\frac{\lambda m^2}{32\pi^2}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}-\gamma_E + 1 +\ln\left(\frac{4\pi\mu^2}{m^2}\right)\right).$$
In $\overline{MS}$, after adding the counterterm in the question, this becomes
$$\Sigma(p^2)=-\frac{\lambda m^2}{32\pi^2}\left(1 +\ln\left(\frac{\mu^2}{m^2}\right)\right).$$
The two point function is then
$$\frac{1}{p^2+m^2-\Sigma(p^2)}.$$
The pole mass then satisfies $m_p^2=\Sigma(m_p^2)-m^2$ (notice that this is different from what I wrote in the question) and therefore
$$m_p^2=-m^2\left(1+\frac{\lambda}{32\pi^2}\left(1 +\ln\left(\frac{\mu^2}{m^2}\right)\right)\right).$$
However, we could have just as well worked in terms of the bare parameters. There the self-energy would have been
$$\Sigma_0(p^2)=-\frac{\lambda_0 m_0^2}{32\pi^2}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}-\gamma_E + 1 +\ln\left(\frac{4\pi\mu^2}{m_0^2}\right)\right),$$
without the introduction of any counterterms. The two point function would have then been
$$\frac{1}{p^2+m_0^2-\Sigma_0(p^2)},$$
leading to the pole mass
$$m_p^2=-m_0^2\left(1+\frac{\lambda_0}{32\pi^2}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}-\gamma_E+1 +\ln\left(\frac{4\pi\mu^2}{m_0^2}\right)\right)\right).$$
Using the bare mass given in the question and the fact that $\lambda_0=\lambda+\mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)$, we see that these two pole masses agree. But in this last form it is obvious that both the pole and bare masses cannot be simultaneously independent of $\mu$.

This suggests one should define the bare Lagrangian as
$$S=\int d^Dx\left(\frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^2+\frac{1}{2}m_0^2\phi^2-\frac{\lambda_0}{4!}\phi^4\right),$$
without any $\mu$ factor to make $\lambda_0$ dimensionless. With this we instead have
$$m_p^2=-m_0^2\left(1+\frac{\lambda_0}{32\pi^2}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}-\gamma_E+1 +\ln\left(\frac{4\pi}{m_0^2}\right)\right)\right),$$
with which it is consistent to say that both $m_0^2$ and $m_p^2$ are $\mu$ independent.

Is the mass beta function wrong too? I just realized that at order $0$ in $\hbar$ it isn’t $2m^2$

Thanks for spending some time thinking about this! I appreciate it!

I will expand on this at some point. But the reason why this has to fail from the beginning is that the independence of $\mu$ of the bare and pole masses are not independent from one another. This is because the pole mass can also be written solely in terms of the bare mass.
